# DC Motors Voltage Equation versus Power Equation

Tags: power, dc-motor, torque

I understand the voltage equation and the power equation for DC motors. But somehow I have a problem understanding moving from one to the other. I am not interested in the IR or IdL/Dt so I will ignore those for the moment even though I realize they are important. V_emf is the back emf produced by a given w (angular velocity) times a constant k.

Voltage:     V_in        =      w * k   (i.e. assuming no losses a motor runs at w)

Power:       V_in * I    =      w * torque (assuming no other losses)

If the second equation is divided by I, you get the first; k=torque/I.

**Case 1: w=0.**

Voltage:   V_in     = 0 * k  (plus the losses which in this case are huge but V_emf = 0. Check)

Power:     V_in * I = 0 * torque = 0 (no motion, no power produced. Check)

**Case 2: w= max, torque = 0**

Voltage:  V_in      = Vemf  (The motor accelerates until V_emf = Vin. Check)

Power:    V_in * I  = w * 0 = 0 ( There is no load so no power is used. Check)

**Case 3:  w and torque are somewhere in the middle**

Voltage:  V_in      = V_emf   (Obviously first conceptual problem: V_in is constant, V_emf varies with torque.)

Power:    V_in * I  =  w  * torque  ( but actually there is also V_emf also so not check)

**I can fix the power equation by saying**:

Power:  Vnet = (V_in - V_emf) * I = w * torque

This seems more natural anyway. The first two cases still make sense. But the problem I have now is that the voltage equation now has a component (w * torque / I) that is not derived from Kircoff's laws and doesn't make sense to me.

I believe the final power equation is correct. I also believe the original voltage equation is correct. How can I reconcile the two?

Comment: Where did Vnet come from?

Comment: https://studyelectrical.com/2018/01/voltage-and-power-equations-of-dc-motor-maximum-power-condition.html

Comment: _"I am not interested in the IR"_ - There's your problem. Internal resistance determines how much the generator voltage and speed drops under load. You cannot ignore it.

Comment: Like @BruceAbbott says: ignoring the losses gives rubbish. As you noted yourself, V_in = V_emf is weird. That notion is true. It at least is V_in = V_emf + V_R, where V_R is the drop across the winding resistance. It is one of the parts that causes losses.

Comment: Next, you're missing mechanical losses too. Your final equation will be something like: P_electrical * efficiency = P_motor, where the losses determine the efficiency

Comment: Thanks everyone. V_net was my term for V_in - V_emf. I lay in bed last night also re.thinking about IR. I know how important R is in an RC circuit for example. I will try to rework it this week when I get some free time.

Comment: The conceptual problem remains for me: to balance the power equation (even with loss) there is a load component (even if just frictional). This load component in the power equation disappears in the electrical equation; the load  T * w should become k * w but there is already a k * w term in the electrical equation that represents back emf. These could be equal but the problem is that load should be inversely related to emf. Total power (less losses) is emf + load : more load, less emf. This makes sense from the speed - torque graph. So why isn't mechanical load in the electrical equations?

Comment: From Andy's link: "out of the armature input, some is wasted in I2R loss and the rest is converted into mechanical power within the armature." Then  in a linked page on the same website: "The electric work done in overcoming and causing the current to flow against Eb is converted into mechanical energy developed in the armature...energy conversion in a dc motor is only possible due to the production of back emf Eb" I still don't get this: if there was no back emf, the motor would still work. When w = 0, the motor still wants to turn. I am missing something here.